# Hot-reload coherence cache-config.xml

Tags: java, caching, oracle-coherence

Is there any way to reload Oracle Coherence cache-config.xml (for example : simple-cache-store-config.xml) without restarting node ?
More precise task - is to modify entry's expiration time "on the fly".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so, there are two ways to accomplish expire-delay modification **at "runtime"** :
1. Programmatic = using NamedCache class method : put(Object oKey,Object oValue,long expireDelay)
2. Settings-style = using Enterprise Manager Cloud Control for Coherence : there is option "ExpiryDelay".